# Liquibase : Invalid argument '--url': missing required argument

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase

Пишу приложение на Spring Boot. При попытке выполнить команду

```
liquibase generateChangeLog
```

Получаю следующий вывод:

```
$ liquibase generateChangeLog
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 20:51:40 (version 4.27.0 #1525 built at 2024-03-25 17:08+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.27.0
Liquibase Open Source 4.27.0 by Liquibase
Error parsing command line: Invalid argument '--url': missing required argument. If you need to configure new liquibase project files and arguments, run the 'liquibase init project' command.

For detailed help, try 'liquibase --help' or 'liquibase <command-name> --help'
```

Но у меня указан `url` в файле `liquibase.properties`. Он лежит в папке `src/main/resources`:

```
changeLogFile=@project.basedir@/src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog.yaml
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/itrum_db
username=postgres
password=postgres
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:ru.terentyev.itrumtesttask.entities
ignoreClasspathPrefix=true
```

**src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog.yaml**:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - logicalFilePath: db/changelog/db.changelog-lesson1.yaml
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: dmitriy
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: wallets
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: uuid
                  type: uuid
                  autoIncrement: false
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: balance
                  type: bigint
                  constraints:
                    unique: false
                    nullable: false
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.terentyev</groupId>
    <artifactId>itrumtesttask</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>itrumtesttask</name>
    <description>Test task for Itrum</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>liquibase.properties</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Как исправить ошибку?
Или нужно где-то в другом месте указать, чтобы `url` брался из `liquibase.properties`? Если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Справился с проблемой. Нужно было заменить эту строку в `pom.xml`:

```
<propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
```

на эту:

```
<propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
```

и запускать команду из папки `src/main/resources`